# Python 2.7.1: Inconsistent output from os.path.isdir()

Tags: python

I'm building a Python ISO generation app, and I'm getting some wierd output from os.path.isdir(). I'm running Arch Linux with Python 2.7.1.

I have the following folder structure:
/home/andrew/create_iso/Raw_Materials/
/home/andrew/create_iso/Raw_Materials/test_cd/

`[andrew@Cydonia Raw_Materials]$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 andrew andrew 4096 Feb 23 10:20 test_cd`

As you can see, test_cd/ is a normal Linux folder. However, when I run os.path.isdir(), I get different results depending on whether it's part of my for loop or whether I hard code it.

```
import os
>>>for folders in os.listdir('/home/andrew/create_iso/Raw_Materials/'):
...  os.path.isdir(folders)
False

>>>os.path.isdir('/home/andrew/create_iso/Raw_Materials/test_cd')
True
```

I thought maybe there was something wierd in the output I'm getting from os.listdir(), but that also seems to check out:

```
>>>os.listdir('/home/andrew/create_iso/Raw_Materials/')
['test_cd']
```

Any idea why it's treating these cases different? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'test_cd' by itself is not a directory.  You need to do an `os.path.join` to get the absolute path to the directory, and then call `isdir` on that.

Comment: That's kinda confusing, but it makes sense - test_cd is really just a string without directory tree metadata.

Answer (score 4):

You need to append folders to the '/home/andrew'... path.

```
folder_path = '/home/andrew/create_iso/Raw_Materials/'
for folder in os.listdir(folder_path):
    os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_path, folder))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for `test_cd` in the current directory, not in the directory you're reading with `os.listdir`. The current directory is probably the same one that contains your script, and it probably contains no item named `test_cd`. `os.path.isdir()` returns `False` when the file is not found, *as well as* when the file exists but is not a directory. As others have said, use `os.path.join()` to build a full path.